# Which constructor (or implicit conversion) is called when passing a pointer to the constructor?

Tags: c++

```
class Test {
    public:
 
    Test() {
        std::cout << "constructing" << std::endl;
    }
     Test(Test &t) {
        std::cout << "calling copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Test(Test &&t) {
        std::cout << "calling move constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Test& operator=(const Test& a){
        std::cout << "calling = constructor" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

Test* t1 = new Test(); 
Test* t2 (t1); // what's being called here
```

When passing a pointer to a constructor like t2, what constructor is called? (Or implicit conversion and then constructor?) This code just prints "constructing" as a result of t1 being constructed.

Comment: Neither: it's just a copy of the pointer.

Comment: Got it, thanks, so somewhere in C++'s implementation there's a copy constructor for pointers that's being called?

Comment: @edie -- in a sense, yes, but the copy constructor for a pointer (and for any other builtin type) just copies the value.There is no definition of a copy constructor anywhere; the compiler knows what to do, and generates code that does that directly.

Comment: Tangential: signature of your copy constructor should be `Test(const Test &t)` (or, by convention, `Test(const Test &other)`).  You got it right for `operator=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Test* t2 (t1);
```

is direct-initialization. Direct-initialization considers constructors for class types, but `Test*` is a pointer type, not a class type. Non-class types do not have constructors.

For a pointer type, direct-initialization with a single expression in the parenthesized initializer simply copies the value of the expression into the new pointer object (potentially after implicit conversions, which are not necessary here).

So `t2` will simply have the same value as `t1`, pointing to the object created with `new Test();`.